# Invalid bind expression type of String for column of type Date

Tags: apex

```
dt = restReq.params.get('date');


 String s=string.valueOf(dt);
```

I am trying to convert date to string and i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that your SOQL is trying to bind a Date field to a String value:

```
String s = String.valueOf(dt);
sobject[] records = [select ... from ... where somedatefield = :s];
```

Instead, you will want to make the variable a date:

```
Date d = DateTime.valueOf(dt);
sobject[] records = [select ... from ... where somedatefield = :d];
```

**Note**: You'll need to determine which DateTime method you need (e.g. DateTime.parse, etc) based on the date's format.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. Cheers!!